# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':Aware@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aars

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use pocketsphinx in my android app and its giving me trouble. I've installed it as outlined here: [PocketSphinx on Android](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/#referencing-the-library-in-an-android-project), specifically by importing the .aar. Here is my code:

project build.gradle file:

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```

Application build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kutz.connor.Aware"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        DexOptions {
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation project(':aars')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the error I get is

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':Aware@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aars.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':Aware@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aars.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':Aware@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :aars.
```

when I try to build the project. Upon research I've seen that this probably has to do with updating Androdi Studio to 3.0.

**Some solutions I have tried**:

Adding matchingFallbacks for debug, release in the build.gradle function

Creating a settings.gradle for the project

Any help would be great. I've seen on posts to move all buildtypes to the app gradle as well but I'm unsure of exactly how to do that.

**EDIT**

Here is the settings.gradle file in the project folder, it has only one line

```
include ':Aware', ':aars'
```

Comment: Post your settings.gradle in the root folder

Comment: Ok, just did that

Comment: May be you have same project inside the aars project. Do you have a build.gradle file inside that module?

Comment: I do not have a build.gradle for the aars project, should I just make a new file and copy the build.gradle for the app module?

Comment: Yes if you include it in the settings.gradle and you want to use it as implementation project(':aars')

Comment: I found I had to change the `apply plugin` line within the package/module/library `build.gradle` file of my import e.g. `apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'` -> `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` when transitioning from some of my modules to accomodate the new app bundle format.